# Triple Integral of $1/\sqrt{2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ over unit sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm studying triple integrals (physics major), and I'm having trouble solving this little beast:

$$
\iiint_V \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 + x^2 +y^2 +z^2}} \,dx\,dy\,dz$$

where V is $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

Of course we use spherical coordinates:

$$I = \iiint_V \frac{r^2 \sin φ}{\sqrt{2+r^2}} \,dr\,dφ\,dθ$$

In order to solve the first integral over r I simplified the denominator using $$\sqrt{2+r^2} = \sqrt{2\left(1+\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{2}^2}\right)}$$

in order to substitute $\tan ω = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$. However again even this integral leads to 2 pages of computations and I still haven't reached a correct result.

Is there any shortcut I'm not seeing?

PS: The limits of $r,θ,φ$ are the standard ones since we are on the unit sphere.

Comment: Hint: Try $r = \sqrt{2} \sin (\omega)$

Comment: The substitution is appropriate. What result do you get?

Comment: @Demosthene Right now I'm down at $$2\int \sinω \tanω \frac{1}{1 + ω^2} dω$$ just for the first integral. Thanks!

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks that might work too! The 1st answer seems to be spot on. That was the shortcut I was looking for :)

Comment: You've made a mistake, but I can't tell you where if I can't see your derivation.

Comment: I find $$\int_0^1\dfrac{r^2}{\sqrt{2+r^2}}dr=-\sinh^{-1}\left(2^{-1/2}\right)+\dfrac{ \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Comment: @Demosthene You were right sir. Many thanks. It was an error in the derivation of dr. I said the following:
$$ dr = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1 + ω^2}dω$$

which is clearly wrong since  $$\frac{d}{{dx}}\tan x = \frac{1}{{\cos ^2 {x} }}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

$$\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{a^2 + r^2}} = \sqrt{a^2 + r^2} - \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2 + r^2}}$$

These two terms are now standard integrals, equal respectively to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \left( r \sqrt{a^2 + r^2} + a^2 \ln(\sqrt{a^2 + r^2} + r) \right)$ and $-a^2 \cdot \ln(\sqrt{a^2 + r^2} + r)$

Hence

$$\int_0^1 \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{2 + r^2}} dr = \left[  \frac{1}{2} r \sqrt{r^2 + 2} - \ln(\sqrt{2 + r^2} + r) \right]_0^1 = \ ...$$

Comment: Wow! Many thanks. That seems to be the tip/shortcut I was looking for :) I'll work out the full solution in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\root{2 + r^{2}} - r=t\ \imp\ r = \frac{1}{t} - \half\,t}$ such that:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}\frac{r^{2}}{\root{2 + r^{2}}}\,\dd r}
=\int^{\root{3}- 1}_{\root{2}}\pars{\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{4}\,t - \frac{1}{t^{3}}}
\,\dd t
=\color{#66f}{\large\half\,\bracks{\root{3} + \ln\pars{2 - \root{3}}}}
\\[5mm]&\approx{\tt 0.2075}
\end{align}

Comment: I think you have the sings reversed in expression of r. Shouldn't it read $$r = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{t}$$ ?

Comment: @LeonidasTsampros No. The only detail was that the 'new' integration limits were in reverse order. I edited the answer such that $r=0$ leads to $t=\sqrt{2}$ and $r=1$ leads to $t=\sqrt{3} - 1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by [WA](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E2%2Fsqrt%7B2%2Bx%5E2%7D+dx&x=0&y=0) gives
$$
\int \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{2+r^2}} \,dr 
=
\frac{1}{2}r\sqrt{r^2+2} - \sinh^{-1}\left( \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+ C
$$